# Php general ledger query

Tags: php, accounts

I am new in PHP I want to know how to create general ledger.

I have two tables invoice and payment received.

I want to create general ledger using both tables.

```
mysql_query("select * from invoice");
mysql_query("select * from invoice");
```

Comment: Lookup "how to ask a question" on stackoverflow for important guidelines.

Comment: Warning: The `mysql_*` functions are [no longer supported or maintained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942). They were [deprecated in PHP 5.5.0](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) and [removed in PHP 7.0.0](https://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#function.mysql-connect-refsynopsisdiv). You are strongly encouraged to migrate to either [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to count the total, you can do it like this:

```
$total = mysql_query("SELECT count(money) as total FROM invoice");//your query string
$res = mysql_fetch_array($total);
$count = $res['total']; //statistics
```